# Why masses connected by via a string have same accleration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, spring, string, free-fall

[image]

The system is in equilibrium, and the following discussion occurs after spring-1 is cut.

Now, as soon as spring-1 is cut it is clear that the spring force acting one M due to spring-1,will be zero instantly. Now it is said that as the two masses **2M** and **M** are connected via a string, due to which, they will both have the same acceleration. This last conclusion is the one which I don't understand.

---

***My thought on the problem-:***

My thoughts on this thing was,**just after** the cut takes place, the string will lose its tautness, and the mass M attached to the string will tend to free fall, and as the string has lost its tautness thus mass 2M will fall down with the spring force by spring 2 and gravity, with an acceleration of **1.5 X g**.

Comment: Put a space after a punctuation, it makes the sentences easier to read.

Comment: In an ideal case, with mass-less spring and string, the string or spring have nothing to do with the problem. After the cut, masses $M$ and $2M$ will be subject to the same acceleration by gravity. Hence they will not move relative to one another.

Comment: Also, there are two bodies of mass M in the picture which you have shown.  This causes me some confusion, and, I think I may be able to answer if you were to distinguish between the two.

Comment: Sir,everything about the  system is correct.

Comment: I hope you meant to write, in your penultimate line, "thus mass 2M will fall down with the spring force by spring **2** and gravity".

Comment: Ohh,sorry for that,that might have created a great misconception,thanks for correcting me..

Answer (score 2):

We know that the tension in spring $2$ is determined by its extension, which does not change immediately after spring $1$ is cut. So the tension in spring $2$ immediately after spring $1$ is cut is $Mg$ - which also means that the instantaneous acceleration of the lower mass is zero.

If we assume that the tension in the string is $T$ then the net downwards force on the central mass is $Mg + 2Mg - T$ so we have

$3Mg - T = 2Ma_2$

where $a_2$ is the downwards acceleration of the central mass. Similarly, for the upper mass we have

$T + Mg = Ma_1$

where $a_1$ is the downwards acceleration of the central mass.

Eliminating $T$ from these two equations gives us

$4Mg = Ma_2 + 2Ma_2 \\ \Rightarrow a_1 + 2a_2 = 4g$

But if the string were slack, we would have $a_1=g$, so $a_2=\frac 3 2 g$ and so $a_2 > a_1$ - which is impossible if the string is slack. So we can assume that the string is not slack, which means that

$\displaystyle a_1=a_2= \frac 4 3 g$

Note that the acceleration of the centre of mass of all three masses is the weighted sum of their individual accelerations, which is

$\displaystyle \frac 1 {4M} \left( M \frac {4g} 3 + 2M \frac {4g} 3 + M.0 \right) = g$

as we expect.

Comment: Sir,you are absolutely correct,I have thought the same thing,but the problem with this is ,we are calculating everything just after cutting.So,as you have calculated the acceleration of the masses 2M and M seperately ,assuming that there were no strings between them and got 3/2g and g as there acceleration respectively.Now to keep the string between them taut,the mass 2M needs to move down a bit,but if it moves down,then it will takes some seconds,and in that time,the elongation in the spring 2 will also change thus,the accleartion in mass M below,will not be zero any more

Comment: @PATRICK Thinking about what happens after the masses "move down a bit" is the wrong approach. We are calculating the accelerations *immediately* after the top spring is cut. - nothing moves. The string is assumed to be inextensible, so its tension changes instantaneously - unlike the lower spring which takes time to contract and change its tension. So we can assume that the tension in the lower spring is still $Mg$, whereas the tension in the string immediately changes from $3Mg$ to $\frac 1 3 Mg$.

Answer (score 0):

Before the top spring is cut, the tensions in the bottom spring and the string are $Mg$ and $3Mg$ respectively. We can show this by considering the equilibrium of the lower two masses.

When it comes to considering accelerations when the top spring is cut, I found it instructive to think about what would happen if the string were actually another spring. This would not alter the tensions before the top spring was cut. The instant after it was cut, the tensions would not change, because the middle spring (the one replacing the string) would need to contract by a finite amount in order change its tension, and it couldn't do so without the top two masses changing their relative position – which they cannot do instantaneously. Thus the acceleration of the top mass immediately after the top spring was cut would be $4g$ and that of the middle mass would be zero.

Comment: But the acceleration of the middle mass *cannot* be greater than that of the top mass because the string (which we assume is taut, inextensible and infinitely strong) prevents that.

Comment: I thought I'd deleted this post. It is silly.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach (to avoid being confused by gravity) is to use the principle of equivalence of relativity, and suppose that just after the cut, everything is in the outer space without gravity.

The bottom mass is under a upwards force of $mg$ due to the deflection of the spring, and an acceleration $\frac{mg}{m} = g$.

The same force is applied by the spring to the middle mass.

Now there is a bifurcation:

1. If we take the string only as a connecting, without any elastic property, only a movement of the middle mass can move the upper one. They form one unique mass $3m$ together. So, both will have a downwards acceleration:
   $$a = \frac{mg}{3m} = \frac{g}{3}$$

If we now return to the gravitational environment, it is necessary to add $g$ downwards to both accelerations.

Bottom mass: $a_b = 0$
Middle and upper mass: $a_m = a_u = \frac{4g}{3}$

2. If it is a real string, it is still elastic deformed just after the cut (no matter how small is the deformation), and there is a net downwards force $F = 3mg$ in the upper mass, and an acceleration $a_u = \frac{3mg}{m} = 3g$

The middle mass has a net upwards force $3mg - mg = 2mg$ and acceleration $a_m = \frac{2mg}{2m} = g$

The bottom mass has a net upwards force $mg$ and and acceleration $a_b = \frac{mg}{m} = g$

Returning to the gravitational field, and adding $g$ downwards:

$a_u = 4g$
$a_m = 0$
$a_b = 0$

I believe that the only reason to put the name string instead of spring is to take it only as a connecting tool, so $(1)$ seems the right answer.